# Create register: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable Express and Promisify

Tags: node.js, express, node-promisify

The following code shows me the error:

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

There seems to be a problem here with the `es6-promisify` library

```
 const {promisify} = require("es6-promisify");

 exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name });
    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    res.send("all has been saved")
    next(); // pass to authController.login
  };
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place to submit bugs, you should do that in the [Github Issues area](https://github.com/digitaldesignlabs/es6-promisify/issues) for that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be about **es6-promisify** library bug. I suggest changing **es6-promisify** to build-in node module **util**.

A new working solution should be

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name });
  const register = promisify(User.register).bind(User);
  await register(user, req.body.password);
  next();
}
```

Note that just apply **await** in front of  User.register method is not working for sure due to this method is still a normal callback function, you can see on this [passport-local-mongoose test case](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/master/test/passport-local-mongoose.js)